# trying to perform arithmetic operations on numbers expressed as a character string

Tags: java, string

I am obviously new to java. I have this assignment where I am supposed to write a program which performs arithmetic operations on numbers expressed as a character string.

I don't know where to start. I have tried googling, looking through my book, big java, in the relevant sections but can't seem to find helpful information.

I found a program that have completed the same assignment but I want to learn write my own and understand how to go about.

I can show you one of the methods that he used.

I have bolded a few comments where I get confused.

```
public static String add(String num1, String num2) {


    while (num1.length() > num2.length()) {

        num2 = "0" + num2;

    }


    while (num1.length() < num2.length()) {

        num1 = "0" + num1;


    }


    int carry = 0;  // whats the point of this?

    String result = "";

    // look at the for loop bellow. I don't understand why he is converting the strings to ints this                     
    // way? this doesn't  even return the correct inputed numbers?

    for (int i = 1; i <= num1.length(); i++) {  

        int digit1 = Character.getNumericValue(num1.charAt(num1.length() - i));

        int digit2 = Character.getNumericValue(num2.charAt(num2.length() - i)); 

        int sum = digit1 + digit2 + carry;

        carry = sum / 10;   

        result = (sum % 10) + result;

        // why is he dividing the sum with 10? If the user inputs a 5, would't the result become 0.5

        // which isn't a valid int value? this line is also confusing

    }


    if (carry > 0) {

    result = carry + result;

    }


    return result;


}
```

Any explanation or even guidance to a page where I am trying to do is explained would be very appreciated.

Comment: He's performing the addition the same way you would with a pencil and paper, you start by adding the right most digit and move your way to the left. The `carry` is exactly that, the value that went over a single digit; the division by ten is necessary because the operation is shifting the value for the next `sum = digit1 + digit2 + carry;`

Comment: Have you been explicitly banned from first converting the string to a primitive numeric type, then performing the operation?

Comment: an integer / an integer is an integer. 5/10 or indeed 9/10 is 0.

Comment: @Bohemian I am not sure. this is what the assignment says "The problem is to perform various arithmetic operations on these numbers.
In each operation one must examine the character strings digit by digit and
determine the next digit in the result. Thus a new character string is created,
representing the result of the operation."

Comment: @ali sounds like you must only use strings. You may find a utility methods useful to make your code easier to read, eg `int digitAtPosition(String number, int position) { return number.charAt(number.length() - position) - '0'; }`, where position is the power of ten of the digit (ie rightmost == 0). Of course, you’ll need to check length vs position etc, but utility methods help clean up the main code so you can read it and debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found a program that have completed the same assignment but I want to learn write my own and understand how to go about.

That is the right idea.  I suggest that you *stop* looking at the code that you found.  (I'm sure that your teachers don't want you to look up the answers on the internet, and you will learn more from your homework if you *don't do it*.)

So how to proceed?

(I am assuming that you are supposed to code the methods to do the arithmetic, and not just convert the entire string to a primitive number or `BigInteger` and use them to do the arithmetic.)

Here's my suggested approach:

1. What you are trying to program is the equivalent of doing long addition with a pencil and paper.  Like you were taught in primary school.  So I suggest that you think of that pencil-and-paper procedure as an algorithm and work out how to express it as Java code.  The first step is to make sure that you have the steps of this algorithm clearly in your head.
2. Try to break the larger problem into smaller sub-problems.  One sub-problem could be how to convert a character representing a decimal digit into an integer; e.g. how to convert `'1'` to `1`.  Next sub-problem is adding two numbers in the range `0` to `9` and dealing with the "carry".  A final sub-problem is converting an integer in the range `0` to `9` into the corresponding character.

   Write sample Java code fragments for each sub-problem.  If you have been taught about writing methods, some of the code fragments *could* be expressed as Java methods.
3. Then you assemble the solutions to the sub-problems into a solution for the entire problem.  For example, adding two (positive!) numbers represented as strings involves looping over the digits, starting at the "right hand" end.
4. As part of your program, write a collection of test cases that you can use to automate the checking.  For example:

   ```
     String test1 = add("8", "3");
     if (!test1.equals("11")) {
         System.out.println("test1 incorrect: expected '11' go '" +
                            test1 + "'");
     }
   ```

Hints:

- You can "explode" a `String` to a `char[]` using the `toCharArray` method.  Or you could use `charAt` to get characters individually.
- You can convert between a `char` representing a digit and an `int` using `Character` methods or with some simple arithmetic.
- You can use `+` to concatenate a string and a character, or a character and a string.  Or you can use a `StringBuilder`.
- If you need to deal with signed numbers, strip off and remember the sign, do the appropriate computation, and put it back; e.g. "-123 + -456" is "- (123 + 456)".
- If you need to do long multiplication and long division, you can build them up from long addition and long subtraction.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. I found it very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a number in String format to a number in numeric format by “long n = Long. parseLong(String)” or “Long n = Long.valueOf(String)”. Then just add 2 long variables using a + sign. It will throw NumberFormatException if the String is not a number but a character. Throw that exception back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the code pads both numbers to equal lengths.

```
e.g. "45" + "789" will be padded to "045" + "789"
```

The for loop evaluates one character at a time, starting from the right hand most.

```
iteration 1 -> (right most)
   5 + 9 -> 14 
   when you divide an integer with another integer, you will always get an integer.
   hence carry = 14/10 = 1 (note: not 1.4, but 1, because an int cannot have decimal places)
   and the remainder is 14 % 10 = 4  (mod operation)
   we now concatenate this remainder into "result" (which is "" empty)
       result = (14%10)+ result; // value of result is now "4"

iteration 2 -> (second right most)
   4+8 + (carry) = 4 + 8 + 1 = 13
   same thing, there is a carry of 13/10 = 1
   and the remainder is 13%10 = 3
   we concatenate the remainder into result ("4")
       result = (13%10) + result = 3 +"4" = "34"

iteration 3-> 
   0 + 7 + 1 = 8
   this time 8/10 will give you 0 (hence carry = 0)
   and 8%10 will give a remainder of 8.
   result = 8 + "34" = "834"
```

after all the numbers have been evaluated, the code checks if there are anymore carry. if the value is more than 0, then that value is added to the front of the result.